# Redirect domain except those users coming from a specific IP address

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache

I've got a Apache web server that serves 2 domains, now in my school one domain is blocked; one isn't (same webpage for the moment). I want that if people connect to my old domain (the one that isn't blocked) to get redirected, unless it comes from the school's IP address. How would I do this, I know it has something to do with `.htaccess` but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !203\.0\.113\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `203.0.113.123` is the school's external IP address.

This is the same as any other domain to domain redirect, just with an additional condition to exclude requests coming from the above IP address.

**UPDATE:** If you do this redirect in your main server config, then you may need to change the above `RewriteRule` slightly. If it's in a `<Directory>` container then leave as-is, otherwise if it's directly in the server config (or virtual host) then change it to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've set this up but I need to test it at home to make sure it works from another IP.

Comment: Then change the school IP address to your home IP address... you are expected to think a little :)

Comment: ...but make sure the browser cache is cleared afterwards (or test with a `302`).

Comment: Nope...Didn't work... I added in my .htaccess "ErrorDocument 404 /404.html" and that didn't work either...

Comment: What happened? An error? Nothing? Incorrect redirect? Are you sure you have the correct IP address(es)? Do you (or "did you") already have an unconditional domain redirect? Is `.htaccess` / mod_rewrite enabled and working on your server? What has `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` got to do with this? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I own the (Arch) VPS that it is running on, I know it is the right IP, didn't mess with the httpd.conf so if mod_rewrite is enabled by default then yes if not please let me know how...My point with ErrorDocument is that .htaccess does not appear to respond to to the directives I give it... and the .htaccess I am modifing is in the root web server directory, and to my knowledge there shouldn't be any others...

Comment: ".htaccess does not appear to respond to to the directives I give it" - Ah... If with that `ErrorDocument` directive, the file `/404.html` is not served and you just get the standard 404 response then it sounds like `.htaccess` files are not enabled. You'll need something like `AllowOverride All` in the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the server config. If you then start getting 500 errors then you'll also need to install/enable mod_rewrite. However, if you have access to the server config, it will be preferable to do this in your server config instead of `.htaccess`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note that any changes to the server config will naturally require an Apache restart.

Comment: I now got my .htaccess working but when I add that in I get a 500 Error.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? As mentioned above, if mod_rewrite is not enabled then the above will naturally trigger a 500 error. (If you ever get a 500 error then you should check your servers error log for a meaningful description that details the error.)

Comment: Ok, I clearly have no idea what I'm doing, so I got mod_rewrite enabled. and I now get a different error... when I type in old.domain I get redirected to new.domain// (with the // at the end) and chrome says "DOMAIN.com didn’t send any data." and the I comment out that script in .htaccess and I still get redirected...

Comment: Sorry, if you were using the second `RewriteRule` there was an additional (erroneous) slash in the substitution (now removed). Whilst this shouldn't have caused a problem if requesting physical files (Apache collapses multiple slashes in the request), it could well have caused problems for any application that routes URLs using other methods. If you still get redirected after removing that directive you are probably seeing a cached response. Clear your browser cache. 301s are cached hard by the browser - for this reason it is often helpful to test with 302 (temporary) redirects.